# PDO Binding parameters to insert from previous select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, db2

When executing the following script, I get an error at my INSERT for invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound.

If I run the insert manually based on the previously selected values  then it's fine. I know the syntax and relationships are all right. My issue is either in how I'm binding parameters or calling the execution.

Again, the first part of this script returns everything it needs, but my issue is occurring right at my insert statement, specifically erroring out after the insert statement is called.

Maybe It's still my lack of experience with PDO but from my docs it seems like this should work.

```
$order_ids = [];
while ($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $order_ids[] = $row['order_id'];
}
if (count($order_ids) > 0) {
    $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($order_ids), '?'));
    $detailStatCheck = "
        SELECT 
             invnoc as INVOICE,
             fstatc as STATUS,
             cstnoc AS DEALER,
             framec AS FRAME,
             covr1c AS COVER,
             colr1c AS COLOR ,
             extd2d AS SHIPDATE,
             orqtyc AS QUANTITY
        FROM GPORPCFL
        WHERE invnoc IN ($placeholders)
    ";
    try {
        $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
        $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute($order_ids);


        $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch();
        print_r($order_ids);
        print_r($count2);
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }

    while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $insertPlacement = "
            INSERT INTO placements_new (sku_id, group_id, dealer_id, start_date, expire_date, locations, order_num)
                SELECT 
                     id, 
                     sku_group_id, 
                     :DEALER, 
                     DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) as start_date,
                     DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date, 
                     :QUANTITY,
                     :INVOICE  
                FROM skus s
            WHERE  s.frame=:FRAME AND s.cover1=:COVER AND s.color1=:COLOR
        ";
        try{
            $insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
            $insertRslt = $insert->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you removed `fstatc as STATUS,` you could fetch as an array and just feed that into the execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually bind the parameters (the error is helpful here: `invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound`). You need to pass `execute()` an array containing the value to be assigned to each parameter:

```
$values = [
    ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
    ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
    ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
    ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
    ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
    ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
    ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
];
```

And then

```
$insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
```

Notice that if you have `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to `false`, you can't have one named parameter used two (or more) times, so you'll need to have `:SHIPDATE` as `:SHIPDATE` and `:SHIPDATE2` and the respective additional value in the `$values` array.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think about creating an array for the parameters. For some reason I thought I was incorrectly executing. So now, if I wanted to only insert based on certain conditions of what the values were, I could create that array and then use the values in an if statement around the insert right?

Comment: Right, inside the `while` check that the conditions are met and only execute the query if they are.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have several conditions that will dictate an insert or update but I'm not able to do a traditional upsert. So I'm going to play with it and see what I can manage out of that

Comment: I was able to use this as is, without applying :SHIPDATE and :SHIPDATE2 so I'm not sure what the deal is with that, but I went ahead and created both in the array to be safe